# Mongo query takes long time on production but fast on development

Tags: mongodb

My query:

```
export const getBimObjectsByProperty = async (projectId: string, forgeFile: string, propertyName: string, value: string, pset?: string,) => {
  try {
    let query = {
      project: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(projectId),
      forgeFile: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(forgeFile),
      properties: {
        $elemMatch: {
          property: propertyName,
          pset,
          value
        }
      }
    };
    const response = await mongoose.model('bimObject').find(query).exec();
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};
```

This takes 4 seconds on development and 17s in production.

The returned data is not much so it's not a bandwidth problem.

What can be the reason it's so slow on production? Is it hardware? Should I increase CPU?

Comment: Chances are your prod collection is slightly bigger than the dev one. Try using indexes. As a side note meaning of optional pset is ambiguous. You'd better remove pset from $elemMatch when it is undefined  or use $exists:false to filter elements without pset.

Comment: Make sense. So bimObjects.index({properties: 1}); on the schema level would do it? I'm not using mongoose when I'm creating the documents. It crashes. So I use a native mongodb insert. Does it effect the index creation? I I've handled the pset. Remove some code in question to make it cleaner.

Comment: no, once index is created on the collection it affects the collection serverside and it doesn't matter what you do driverside. IIRC models creates indexes automatically on init and you can trigger it explicitly with indexSync